# Combine (Merge) two columns from two tables in one SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables which you can also find in the `SQL fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70dba18/9):

```
## Sent Orders ##

    CREATE TABLE Send_Orders (
        Send_Date DATE,
        Product TEXT,
        FlowType TEXT
    );

    INSERT INTO Send_Orders
    (Send_Date, Product, FlowType)
    VALUES 
    ("2017-05-23", "Product A", "Send"),
    ("2018-09-10", "Product B", "Send"),
    ("2018-12-14", "Product B", "Send"),
    ("2019-01-03", "Product A", "Send"),
    ("2019-02-15", "Product C", "Send"),
    ("2017-09-04", "Product C", "Send"),
    ("2019-01-09", "Product A", "Send"),
    ("2019-02-16", "Product A", "Send"),
    ("2019-02-12", "Product A", "Send"),
    ("2019-02-15", "Product C", "Send"),
    ("2018-01-03", "Product B", "Send");


## Return Orders ##

    CREATE TABLE Return_Orders (
        Return_Date DATE,
        Product TEXT,
        FlowType TEXT
    );

    INSERT INTO Return_Orders
    (Return_Date, Product, FlowType)
    VALUES 
    ("2017-06-24", "Product A", "Return"),
    ("2018-07-11", "Product B", "Return"),
    ("2018-12-18", "Product B", "Return"),
    ("2019-02-01", "Product A", "Return"),
    ("2019-02-22", "Product C", "Return"),
    ("2017-10-18", "Product C", "Return"),
    ("2019-04-12", "Product A", "Return"),
    ("2019-02-19", "Product A", "Return"),
    ("2019-03-25", "Product A", "Return"),
    ("2019-04-19", "Product C", "Return"),
    ("2018-05-17", "Product B", "Return");
```

---

Now, I want to run a query and combine the columns `Send_Date` and `Return_Date` in one column called `Event_Date` so the result should look like this:

```
Event_Date      Product      FlowType
2017-05-23       Product A    Send
2017-06-24       Product A    Return
2018-09-10       Product B    Send
2018-07-11       Product B    Return
:                :            :
:                :            :
:                :            :
```

So far I could join the two tables but the dates are displayed in two seperate columns:

```
SELECT s.Send_Date, r.Return_Date, s.Product, s.FlowType
FROM Send_Orders s
JOIN Return_Orders r ON r.Product = s.Product
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

What do I need to change in the SQL to merge them into one column?

Comment: Joins are horizontal UNIONs are vertical https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: Can you explain why for `Product B` you want 1st the row with date = '2018-09-10' and 2nd the row with date = '2018-07-11'?

Comment: Given that the flowtype is always the same, this seems like a redundant column - unless of course you modified the database schema such that you only had one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Send_Date Event_Date, Product, FlowType FROM Send_Orders
UNION ALL
SELECT Return_Date, Product, FlowType FROM Return_Orders
ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. I also updated it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70dba18/25

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT Send_Date as Event_Date,Product,FlowType FROM Send_Orders
UNION ALL
SELECT Return_Date as Event_Date,Product,FlowType FROM Return_Orders
ORDER BY 2
```