# Merge two columns from two tables in one SQL query and combine COUNT and SUM values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following two tables which you can also find in the `SQL fiddle` [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e9dd3/1):

```
CREATE TABLE Send_Orders (
    Send_Date DATE,
    Product TEXT,
    FlowType TEXT,
    Send_Quantity VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Send_Orders
(Send_Date, Product, FlowType, Send_Quantity)
VALUES 
("2017-05-23", "Product A", "Send", "400"),
("2018-09-10", "Product B", "Send", "200"),
("2018-12-14", "Product B", "Send", "600"),
("2019-01-03", "Product A", "Send", "700"),
("2019-02-15", "Product C", "Send", "650"),
("2017-09-04", "Product C", "Send", "380"),
("2019-01-09", "Product A", "Send", "120"),
("2019-02-16", "Product A", "Send", "470"),
("2019-02-12", "Product A", "Send", "920"),
("2019-02-15", "Product C", "Send", "860"),
("2018-01-03", "Product B", "Send", "610");


CREATE TABLE Return_Orders (
    Return_Date DATE,
    Product TEXT,
    DeliveryType TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Return_Orders
(Return_Date, Product, DeliveryType)
VALUES 
("2017-06-24", "Product A", "Return"),
("2018-12-18", "Product B", "Return"),
("2018-12-18", "Product B", "Return"),
("2019-02-01", "Product A", "Return"),
("2019-02-22", "Product C", "Return"),
("2017-10-18", "Product C", "Return"),
("2019-04-12", "Product A", "Return"),
("2019-04-12", "Product A", "Return"),
("2019-04-12", "Product A", "Return"),
("2019-04-19", "Product C", "Return"),
("2018-05-17", "Product B", "Return");
```

---

Now, I want to run a query and combine the columns `Send_Date` and `Return_Date` in one column called `Event_Date` so the result should look like this:

```
Event_Date      Product      FlowType   Quantity
2017-05-23       Product A    Send       400
2017-06-24       Product A    Return       1
2018-09-10       Product B    Send       200
2018-12-18       Product B    Return       2
:                :            :
:                :            :
:                :            :
```

I tried to go with the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057342/combine-merge-two-columns-from-two-tables-in-one-sql-query/60057643#60057643) but it sums up the `quantity` to one date and does not list each date.

```
SELECT Send_Date As Event_Date, Product, FlowType, SUM(Send_Quantity) as Quantity FROM Send_Orders
UNION ALL
SELECT Return_Date, Product, DeliveryType, COUNT("Product") FROM Return_Orders
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

What do I need to change in the `SQL` to merge the columns and list each date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `GROUP BY`.  I think:

```
(SELECT Send_Date As Event_Date, Product, FlowType, 
       SUM(Send_Quantity) as Quantity
 FROM Send_Orders
 GROUP BY Send_Date, Product, FlowType
) UNION ALL
(SELECT Return_Date, Product, DeliveryType, COUNT("Product") 
 FROM Return_Orders
 GROUP BY Return_Date, Product, DeliveryType
)
ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Comment: My guess is one GROUP BY is more efficient than two, but I might be mistaken

Comment: @Strawberry It is too difficult to use one GROUP BY to two separate UNION subqueries which must stay separate...

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed. I also updated it here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e9dd3/4

Comment: @Strawberry . . . That is actually false.  MySQL implements `GROUP BY` using a sort.  Sorting algorithms are O(n log(n)).  Doubling the size of the data more than doubles the time.  Hence two separate aggregations on smaller data would normally be faster.